# Does Docker reduce or mitigate the need for Puppet/Chef et al?

Tags: docker, chef-infra, puppet, devops

I'm not au fait with any of these technologies (embarrassing really), but at my present gig, the company badly needs to automate.

So as I begin to read-up on Puppet and Chef and PowerShell DSC, I then remember that Docker and containerisation is coming to Windows.

Does Docker do away with the need for these tools, or do they work together?

I understand that Docker uses virtualisation technology in the OS, so I get the feeling that Docker solves a different problem, and a configuration tool is still needed but I've no certain, practical knowledge.

Comment: Not really a programming question, might have better luck at serverfault.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that. And then I thought: SO is a silo we need to tear down ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does Docker do away with the need for these tools, or do they work together?

They work together: provisioning and containerization solve different issues, and you actually can provision docker containers themselves with a provisioning tool.
See for instance "[Docker: Using Puppet](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/puppet/)"

Answer (score 1):

Tools like Chef & Puppet are important for configuration, but they do have one weakness that Docker helps to shore up.   They are not always fully idempotent (hype notwithstanding).  In other words, running Chef twice on the same virtual machine may cause unexpected and hard-to-find changes on that machine, and you'd be restoring a backup to get to a known good state.

By contrast, a Docker deployment involves building an entirely new image and swapping it out with your old image.   Rollback involves simply unswapping them and comparing them to diagnose the problems in the new image.

Note that you still might very well use Chef to build your Docker container.   But you might very well not.  Since containers are supposed to run just one process in a particular way, I've found that a series of simple shell commands is way preferable to the overhead entailed by Chef.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet and Chef are configuration management tools, where as Docker is a virtualization tool such as LXC.

Usually you'd be using Chef or puppet to manage Docker containers. For example take a look at [Chef docs](https://docs.chef.io/containers.html).

EDIT as per @ptierno comment.

Comment: puppet and chef are configuration management tools, not for orchestration. puppet leans towards using mcollective for orchestration tasks.

Comment: ptierno, good point, Puppet and Chef are configuration tools. btw, it's quite unusual to use configuration  tools to manager Docker.

Answer (score 0):

In short no, you don't need anything like Chef or Puppet. Of course you can use if like to but it's not required.

If you build your system in such way that everything in containerized then what you need is only a tiny OS like CoreOS or Atomic.

So you just configure your VM via `Cloud-Config` if needed and deploy your container either with cloud config or Docker cli itself. The idea is your machines should have a static state and they can be created whenever you want new one and destroyed when you don't need.

There are other tools that can help with Docker orchestration which another story by itself.

Tools like `Swarm`, `Kubernetes` and `Mesosphere`.
docker-machine is also very helpful for development purpose. (maybe deployment too).

Here is CoreOS example:
    https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config.html

Resource: I do it in production for different apps.

**UPDATE:**

BTW, Docker is not only a visualization technology. It does some sort of containerization (you can call it virtualization too) and that's only a small part of the what Docker can do. Docker can configure, build, ship and run application whit eliminating its dependencies on host machine. And that's why you don't need those classic configuration tools.

Answer (score -1):

Docker is three things: a cool way to run a process, a decent image-based deploy system, and a mediocre system image builder.

The first is not related to config management as those tools aren't involved in running a process, at least not directly. The second takes the place of some amount of config management in production by doing it ahead of time when you build the image. There is still often some need for last-mile config for stuff like service discovery and secrets but this can be handled by lighter tools like consul-templates or confd. The last is where the rub lies. `docker build` is simple, easy to get started with, and mostly unhelpful for complex situations. You get, at most, a single inheritance tree between dockerfiles which makes stuff like multi-axis matrix builds ({app1 app2 app3} x {prod qa dev}) more difficult than it could be. Also building composable abstraction for other groups to use is difficult, though again it isn't impossible. Using something like Packer to drive image builds can produce simpler code sometimes, and supports the full suite of CAPS (Chef, Ansible, Puppet, Salt) tools. This is mostly aimed at the use case where you are treating Docker images like tiny VMs, which I wish fewer people would do, but it's a thing so here we are.